# Is there a statistical test for five groups with averages ONLY?

Tags: statistical-significance, nonparametric, descriptive-statistics, biostatistics, parametric

The data I collected was measuring plant shoot masses and these were extremely small, so I could only find the total mass of the shoots from 30 plants. Hence, I only have the mean and none of the individual values for the shoot masses in each of the five groups. Is there any statistical test that would work with this data set? I cannot seem to find a parametric or non-parametric one.

Comment: Welcome to CV.  We can't answer your question because you don't tell us what you want to test for!  Please edit your post to explain your objective.